# facebook like button on android application is not working properly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have been trying to add facebook like button using Facebook SDK to my android application, but i am facing one issue.
When i click on like button , it successfully like the page, but after that like button does not changes to "Liked" and does not shows likes count.It should look like this but after liking the page it only shows "Like".
[image]

below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

StatusCallback callback;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    LikeView likeView ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Settings.sdkInitialize(this);
         likeView  = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
        likeView.setObjectId("https://www.facebook.com/VehicleDocs");
        likeView.setForegroundColor(-256);
        likeView.setLikeViewStyle(LikeView.Style.STANDARD);
        likeView.setAuxiliaryViewPosition(LikeView.AuxiliaryViewPosition.INLINE);
        likeView.setHorizontalAlignment(LikeView.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
 }

  protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

          uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, null);

          LikeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that stands out here, that would definitely explain the behavior you are seeing is that you have spelled the function like so - "OnActivityResult".

The actual method on Activity that should be overridden is "onActivityResult". The first character ("o") is lower case:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

Additionally, if you are using UiLifecycleHelper, you probably want to add the following lines of code to your onCreate() method:

```
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Also, I would recommend calling into uiHelper from the other Activity lifecycle methods as well.